# Getting CGPath for an image with Alpha channel

Tags: ios, uiimage, drawing, cgpath

How can I get the outline of the image as a `CGPath`?

For example, how can I get the outline of the Google logo (which has an transparent background). This might be slightly complex case. So a solution to handle less complex scenarios will work (for me) as well.

[image: New Google Logo]

Comment: So what you actually need is an auto-vectorizer based on alpha channel? Or you are just looking for a mask?

Comment: The same question. Anyone can help?

Answer (score 2):

I found this a while ago and used it for something I was working on.

[PoketSVG](https://github.com/arielelkin/PocketSVG) is a library that converts scalable vector graphics to CGPaths and UIBezierPaths. Maybe this will help you? Its on GitHub so you can also have a look at what they're doing at the very least if the library itself isn't useful to you.

good luck!

EDIT: when I used the library, I used it to get outlines of vector graphics. Mind you they were solid shapes, rectangles and squares. Again, I think its a good place to start.